# How to pronounce correctly - ютьюб or ютуб?

Tags: произношение

I have got a few Russian friends, who I communicate with in Russian. Many of them use the word youtube. I have noticed that some of them pronounce ютьюб and some - ютуб. I am not sure which one is correct so I use the English pronunciation т.е. ютьюб. Is there a rule on how to pronounce correctly? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On an everyday level, there's no right and wrong way. **Ютьюб** is more conventional and consistent with similar Russian phonetisations, which is why it's the one that would be used in broadcast media and anywhere else that "correctness" is required. **Ютьюб** is also, however, a bit of a disaster as far as euphony and ease of pronunciation are concerned. Still, as a **ютуб** person I think I'm slightly in the minority.

Answer (score 3):

Ютуб, на ютубе only.
Ютьюб - unecessary too overcomplicated to prononce
If you wish look like noob, who can't english, except that one word, and who wish to show that knowledge - you may use that Ютьюб, or actually Ютюб.

Be cool, name it: тытруба, на тытрубе

Answer (score 3):

The version **ютюб** should not be ignored as well.

I find it a good compromise between acknowledging the foreign origin of the word and not twisting one's tongue too much.

Answer (score 1):

По-английски произносится ютюб. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dQPfC8n2dY

А по-русски ютьюб:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Qtg8bPgEww

Comment: в Америке произносится Ютуб

Answer (score 1):

Since `Youtube` is a foreign proper name it should be pronounced according to the foreign language pronunciation rules. So, since `You` + `tube` is pronounced as `[ju]` + `[tju:b]` this should sound like `ютьюб`. And for any russian-speaking person who keeps an eye on his/her pronunciation, saying `ютуб` means to show the ignorance. But there are cultural influence on that (slang, etc.). So `ютьюб` is the correct way to pronounce this, but `ютуб` is rather a slang form which may be widespread.